# Rxjs type Observable<Unknown> is not assignable to Observable<void>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am in the process of upgrading to rxjs v6 from 5, I have also upgraded my typescript version from 2.9.2 to 3.7.4. In one of my angularjs components, I make a call to a service that returns a promise. For ease of use, I convert that into an observable in my component by using the from rxjs function. My code looks like this (with names changed from originals).

```
saveObject(name: string): Observable<void> {
    return from(
            this.myService.saveMyObject(name)
                .then(() => {
                    //Show Save success on ui
                    return;
            }),
        )
        .pipe(
            catchError((error) => {
                // error handling logic
                return of(); // this bit was an attempt to fix the problem
            }),
        );
}
```

The problem I am having is that the saveObject function in the component returns an observable of void, the promise ultimately resolves to void but when I try to return the observable I get an error saying that observable< unknown> is not assignable to observable< void>. Why is typescript/rxjs inferring the type to be unknown and is there anything I can do aside from doing type assertion to get the correct type.

Edit: Removing the pipe altogether does not fix the issue, just the from(promise) is enough to get the error, unfortunately even doing this to tell rxjs that it is an promise of void does not help, it still offers the same error.

```
from<Promise<void>>(//promiseCode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of someone on the rxjs team I discovered it was because I needed to include this option in my tsconfig file.

```
    "lib": ["es2015"],
```

Answer (score 2):

try return `of()` to complete the observable and see if it works.

```
from(this.myService.saveMyObject(name))
.pipe(
    mergeMap(()=>of()),
    catchError((error) => {
        // error handling logic
        return of(); // this bit was an attempt to fix the problem
    }),
);
```

Comment: It didn't work :(, it also warned that the empty function has been deprecated.

Comment: what about returning of() in mergemap?

Comment: That also did not work, I also tried of<void>() to enforce the type and it still did not work.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dh1nrr
try this stackblitz, it seems to work . but i have to say stackblitz might not have the latest typescript version

Comment: Interesting, I downgraded back to 2.9.2 version of typescript, the error now just says can't assign Observable<{}> to type of Observable<void>

Comment: Actually I upgraded the rxjs version to 6.5.3 in your stackblitz and the error popped up, I may be able to downgrade my rxjs version to see if that helps.

Comment: You can always switch return <boolean> instead that'll be an easier fix

Answer (score 1):

That is because the [catchError()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) operator requires you to return an observable. As stated on the documentation, catchError()

```
Gracefully handle errors in an observable sequence.
```

And you are required to return an observable.

```
:warning: Remember to return an observable from the catchError function!
```

If you do not want to return an observable, an alternative to using the catchError operator would be to handle the error on the error callback when you subscribe to the observable.

```
saveObject(name: string): Observable<void> {
  return from(
    this.myService.saveMyObject(name)
            .then(() => {
                //Show Save success on ui
                return;
        }),
    )

}

this.saveObject.subscribe((res) => {
  // handle success
}, (error) => { 
  // handle errors, without the need to return an observable
});
```

Comment: I am returning an observable in the catchError() with of(), I have attempted to do of<void>() and this did not fix the issue. After doing another check it doesn't seem to be in the pipe at all though, removing the pipe entirely does not fix the problem.

Comment: @LachlanD sorry, what do you mean by that..? You are saying that the errors aren't being propagated in  `catchError`?

Comment: Oh sorry to clarify, I removed the pipe entirely so I just had
```
return from(myPromise)
```
and I still receive the same error as before.

Comment: @LachlanD Hmmm.. Just curious, does the `.then()` statement return any values? How about removing the <void> generic?

Comment: It initially had no return statement but I put a return; to be more explicit, it didn't help. For the generic I assume you mean Observable< void>,, if that is the case I can type it as any to get it to work, or unknown also works, but you can't have just Observable with no generic parameters.